# Nginx return header indicating cache status

Tags: nginx, caching, server

In order to make debugging an nginx setup easier it would be nice to add a header to the http response indicating the cache status (HIT/MISS). Is there a way to do this with a simple nginx cache setup such as this?

```
server {
    # ...
    location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    }
}
```

I found basic docs for adding a header using [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) but not how to dynamically change the response based on the cache status.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **add_header** directive and [$upstream_cache_status](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables) embedded variable, that keeps the status of accessing a response cache.

The status can be either “MISS”, “BYPASS”, “EXPIRED”, “STALE”, “UPDATING”, “REVALIDATED”, or “HIT”. :

```
http {
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
 }
```